# Parsing a string with [3:0] substring in it

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, match

I want to store two numbers from a string into two distinct variables - for example, var1 = 3 and var2 = 0 from "[3:0]". I have the following code snippet:

```
String myStr = "[3:0]";
if (myStr.trim().matches("\\[(\\d+)\\]")) {
    // Do something.
    // If it enter the here, here I want to store 3 and 0 in different variables or an array
}
```

Is it possible doing this with split and regular expressions?

Comment: You don't even need regex for this. Just split on `:`, remove the first character from the `0th` element and last character from the `1st` element and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceAll` and `split`

```
String myStr = "[3:0]";
if(myStr.trim().matches("\\[\\d+:\\d+\\]") {
   String[] numbers = myStr.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").split(":");
}
```

Moreover, your `regExp` to match `String` should be `\\[\\d+:\\d+\\]`, if you want to avoid `trim` you can add `\\s+` at start and end to match the spaces.But `trim` is not bad.

**EDIT**

As suggested by `Andreas` in comments,

```
String myStr = "[3:0]";
String regExp = "\\[(\\d+):(\\d+)\\]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStr.trim());

if(matcher.find()) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(a + " : " + b);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3 : 0
```

Comment: The advantage of regex, as used by OP, is that an input that doesn't match the pattern will simply skip the if-statement, as OP likely intended, while this code will react weirdly/badly/fail for invalid input.

Comment: Since you're going to run the regex anyway, why not let it return the matched values, instead of running yet another *two* regex's to get them?

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `trim()`. Enhance you regex instead.

Your regex is missing the pattern for `:` and the second number, and you don't need to escape the `]`.

To capture the matched numbers, you need the `Matcher`:

```
String myStr = "  [3:0]  ";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\[(\\d+):(\\d+)]\\s*").matcher(myStr);
if (m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2));
```

*Output*

```
3, 0
```

Comment: If OP *has to* validate input then this solution is correct choice. It will simply use Matcher to do all the work for us which is storing values we are interested in. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Without any regular expressions you could do this:

```
// this will remove the braces [ and ] and just leave "3:0"
String numberString= myString.trim().replace("[", "").replace("]",""); 

// this will split the string in everything before the : and everything after the : (so two values as an array)
String[] numbers = numberString.split(":"); 

// get the first value and parse it as a number "3" will become a simple 3
int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]) ; 

// get the second value and parse it from "0" to a plain 0 
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```

be carefull when parsing numbers, depending on your input string and what other possibilities there might be (e.g. "3:12" is ok, but "3:02" might throw an error).

Comment: The advantage of regex, as used by OP, is that an input that doesn't match the pattern will simply skip the if-statement, as OP likely intended, while this code will react weirdly/badly/fail for invalid input.

Comment: @Andreas: you are absolutely right. Regex is way better here. I just wanted to show that it is possible to get the numbers without regex (as kon pointed out in his comment). It may be less awesome but maybe easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't need to validate input and you want to simply get numbers from it, you could simply find `indexOf(":")` and `substring` parts which you are interested, in which are:

- from `[` (which is at position 0) till `:`
- and from index of `:` till `]` (which is at position equal to length of string -1)

Your code can look like

```
String text = "[3:0]";
int colonIndex = text.indexOf(':');
String first = text.substring(1, colonIndex);
String second = text.substring(colonIndex + 1, text.length() - 1);
```

Comment: The advantage of regex, as used by OP, is that an input that doesn't match the pattern will simply skip the if-statement, as OP likely intended, while this code will react weirdly/badly/fail for invalid input.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't say that OP should skip `matches` part. My answer is solution which can be used inside that `if` block (after it is corrected).

Comment: Your code implicitly replaces the if-statement by including the `myStr` declaration (which you renamed to `text`). Hard-coding `1` will not work if the text has leading spaces, which the `trim()` in the if-statement would indicate might happen.

Comment: @Andreas True, that is why I updated my answer to show that it is based on assumption that we are sure that input is in valid form. If it is not and it require additional validation using Matcher would be correct solution because it will let us store important parts in capturing groups (you already got my +1 for that).